# Making a sheet from a panel in AppleScriptObjC

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, applescript-objc, cocoa-sheet

Alright, I'm trying to make a sheet appear in my AppleScriptObjC app, based on a panel I've already designed in the 'Interface Builder' .xib file.

I've found a fantastic answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058653/displaying-a-cocoa-window-as-a-sheet-in-xcode-4-osx-10-7-2-with-arc), but it's for Objective-C, and I'm struggling to translate it into AppleScriptObjC.

Here's the code I've tried at the moment:
`beginSheet_modalForWindow_modalDelegate_didEndSelector_contextInfo_(loadingWindow, mainWindow, me, missing value, missing value)`

This just gives me the following error:

```
[AppDelegate titleRefresh:]: *** -[AppDelegate beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to object <AppDelegate @0x10323d4c0: OSAID(4)> (error -10000)
```

The original window is called "mainWindow", the panel to be used as a sheet is called "loadingWindow".

If anybody could help me out, that would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looks like I've managed to figure it out. For anybody else having this issue:

You need to use the code as below:

```
current application's NSApp's beginSheet_modalForWindow_modalDelegate_didEndSelector_contextInfo_(loadingWindow, mainWindow, me, missing value, missing value)
```

…where the Panel you want to use as a sheet is `loadingWindow`, and the main window (which the sheet will appear over) is `mainWindow`.

Similarly, you can close the sheet by using this code:

```
current application's NSApp's endSheet_(loadingWindow)
loadingWindow's orderOut_(loadingWindow)
```

I hope this helps somebody out there! :)