# How to create modal slide-out window in Mac OS?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nswindow

How can I create modal slide-out window/view "in-window" in Xcode like in these screenshot?

I've tried create new Window controller with "Authentication panel style" animation but then I'm receiving only Xcode crashes.

[image: modal window]

Comment: This answer is in Obj-C, but it can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8059193/1796907

Comment: That kind of window is called a ["sheet"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

That kind of modal window is called a Sheet. It's very easy to get this behavior with a Storyboard segue, or programmatically with an `NSViewController` subclass. The example below is just a blank OS X Cocoa application as created by Xcode. (I chose Swift as the language, but it will work the same way with Objective-C.)

The only things I added to the storyboard was a second View Controller for the sheet view, and a label and pushbutton on each view.

### Displaying The Sheet View With A Storyboard Segue

With the Sheet View controller selected and the Connections Inspector tab displayed, connect "Presenting Segues - sheet" to the "Display Sheet" button.

[image]

Connect "Received Actions - dismissController:" to the "Close Sheet" button.

[image]

That's it! There's no code needed to make this example work; just build and run.

---

### Displaying The Sheet View Programmatically

Note that Xcode creates the default project with two custom class files. In the Storyboard, **AppDelegate.swift** is represented in the Application scene:

[image]

We don't need to use the AppDelegate for this example, but you could use it for interaction with the Main Menu, or other things.

The custom **ViewController.swift** custom class will be used to present the sheet. It is represented in the View Controller scene:

[image]

---

To instantiate the Sheet View Controller programmatically, it needs a Storyboard ID. Here, we'll give it the ID "**SheetViewController**". Note that it's still a plain `NSViewController`; we don't need to make it a custom class for this example, but your application might want to:

[image]

---

Displaying the **ViewController.swift** file in the assistant editor, Ctrl-drag a connection from the "Display Sheet" button into the custom class. This will create stub code for an @IBAction function we'll name "displaySheet":

[image]

In the **ViewController.swift** file, we'll implement the Sheet View Controller as a lazy var. It will get instantiated only once, the first time it's accessed. That will happen the first time the displaySheet function is called.

```
//  ViewController.swift

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    lazy var sheetViewController: NSViewController = {
        return self.storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("SheetViewController")
        as! NSViewController
    }()

    @IBAction func displaySheet(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.presentViewControllerAsSheet(sheetViewController)
    }
}
```

Swift 4 version:

```
//  ViewController.swift

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    lazy var sheetViewController: NSViewController = {
        return self.storyboard!.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "SheetViewController"))
        as! NSViewController
    }()

    @IBAction func displaySheet(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.presentViewControllerAsSheet(sheetViewController)
    }
}
```

As in the first example, the "Close Sheet" button is connected to the "dismissController:" action on the Sheet View Controller. Alternatively, you could call that function programmatically from your ViewController class:

```
self.dismissController(sheetViewController)
```

---

For more information, refer to the Apple "Sheets Programming Topics" document:
   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html

Comment: What is best ways to call that controller programmatically?

Comment: I have expanded the answer to include instructions and code to implement this programmatically.

Comment: Which method of main/first viewcontroller is called when you close the sheet window? I want to reload the table which I have on view controller whenever sheet window is dismissed.

Comment: @avi One way to accomplish that would be to subclass the sheetViewController, instead of just using a plain NSViewController.

Comment: How to get result back from the sheetViewController before the sheet gets dismissed?

Answer (score 3):

**Objective-C version:**

```
- (IBAction)displaySheet:(id)sender {
    NSStoryboard *storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    NSViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"SheetViewController"];
    [self presentViewControllerAsSheet:vc];
}
```